# ACPI script , how to know about current TTY displaying to users?

Tags: linux, bash, xorg, acpi

I'm running a script in acpi , if current displayed virtual terminal , switch back to the terminal X11 is running ; else switch to tty1.

So the only problem is , how can i use a program to get the name of current displayed terminal ?

Any suggestions ? `tty` won't help , because it only get the terminal , that the it is running from , not the displaying one.

Many thanks !

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have to wonder why you need to do that, but you may need to write a program that uses the `VT_*` `ioctl()`s in `console_ioctl(4)`.

Comment: Note of course that the active VT can change immediately after you've tested it, before you have time to act on that information.